# wpf combobox binding issue

Tags: wpf, combobox

when i bind one combobox with other combobox items... with the following code

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo1, Path=Items}" Name="cbo2"  />
```

it works fine but when i select something from cbo1 and come back to select something in cbo2.. it doesn't list anything nor cbo1 does...

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Items property is a CollectionView which wraps the ItemsSource, and includes things like the currently selected item, sort order, etc.  If you set ItemsSource on an ItemsControl, your data is automatically wrapped in a CollectionView, and that's what gets set as the Items property.  I suspect that this class isn't suitable for sharing between two controls.

If you're using ItemsSource to set the data on cbo1, you could maybe bind to ItemsSource instead?  That is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo1, Path=ItemsSource}" Name="cbo2"  />
```

Haven't had chance to test this, but it's an educated guess :-)